# How can I easily convert a Pandas barplot to horizontal?

Tags: python, pandas, graph, bar-chart

I'm trying to plot a barplot with horizontal bars. Is there any way I could do this adapting the script below?

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax = df['colum_1'].plot(kind='bar',
                                figsize=(14,8),
                                title="Column1");
```

I know that there is the barh function, but I was wondering if there is any adaptation from the code above to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change kind from ‘bar’ to ‘barh’

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax = df['colum_1'].plot(kind='barh', figsize=(14), title="Column1");
```

**Update**

To make sure that they don't overlap. Use the following approach:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,2)
axs[0] = df['colum_1'].plot(kind='bar', figsize=(14), title="Column1")
axs[1] = df['colum_1'].plot(kind='barh', figsize=(14), title="Column1")
```

Comment: It works, but now I have a problem that the two subplots are crossing each other. Any suggestion on how to separate them? The legend from subplot(122) is getting on the bars from subplot(121)

Comment: I have updated the answer to reflect your follow-up question. Thank you for your patience.